# Open links in the amazon application with android intent

Tags: javascript, android, android-intent

I am looking for a solution to open amazon pages directly in the amazon application. I found the product intent scheme, like this one, and it works:

```
String url = "com.amazon.mobile.shopping://amazon.it/products/ASIN";
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Now I'm looking for the scheme to open promotional pages or other pages, i managed to isolate the following script used by amazon to redirect the links in the application, but i can't build a valid android intent.

```
<script>
P.when('deeplinking-utils').execute(function (DeepLinkingUtils) {
    new DeepLinkingUtils.DeepLinkInstance({
      "webUrl":         "https://www.amazon.it/stores/page/44356AF7-3F18-4DD1-B225-78D8F6C4AE59?_encoding=UTF8&ref_=pe_undef&rw_useCurrentProtocol=1",
      "appStoreUrl":    "market://details?id=com.amazon.mShop.android.shopping&referrer=utm_campaign%3Dm2cab%26utm_source%3Dm2cab_pdown%26utm_medium%3Dpdown",
      "appUrl":         "intent://amazon.it/stores/page/44356AF7-3F18-4DD1-B225-78D8F6C4AE59?rw_useCurrentProtocol=1&ref=pe_undef&chgexp=MSHOP&dl_sid=261-1156871-3045023#Intent;scheme=com.amazon.mobile.shopping.web;package=com.amazon.mShop.android.shopping;S.browser_fallback_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.it%2Fstores%2Fpage%2F44356AF7-3F18-4DD1-B225-78D8F6C4AE59%3Frw_useCurrentProtocol%3D1%26ref_%3Dpe_undef;end",
      "method":         DeepLinkingUtils.Method.INTENTS,
      "action":         "AutoRedirectAttempted",
      "refTag":         "mm_an_eml_attempt",
      "failAction":     "AutoRedirectFailed",
      "failRefTag":     "mm_an_eml_fail",
      "campaignId":     "Redirector_EmailRedirector",
      "clientToken":    "EmailRedirector",
      "treatmentId":    "an_em",
      "openWebUrlOnSuccess": true,
      "autoRedirect":   true,
      "timeout":        1000,
      "fallbackMethod": DeepLinkingUtils.Fallback.WEBURL
    });
});
</script>
```

do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to set package for Intent you are trying to start.

```
String url = "https://www.amazon.it/stores/page/44356AF7-3F18-4DD1-B225-78D8F6C4AE59?_encoding=UTF8&ref_=pe_undef&rw_useCurrentProtocol=1";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url))
intent.setPackage("com.amazon.mShop.android.shopping")
startActivity(intent);
```

But don't forget about resolving. Because if amazon can't handle it that it will lead to an app crash

```
PackageManager packageManager = getActivity().getPackageManager();
if (intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: It does not work, the amazon application is not found even if it is installed on the device. `No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=https://www.amazon.it/... pkg=com.amazon.mShop.android.shopping }`

Comment: @tecn603 does amazon app appears in dialog if you are trying to open it without calling setPackage? If it is not that means that amazon unable to open that url

Comment: Amazon is able to open the url because the script I posted in the question is able to open the url from the application through the amazon page opened by chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution, use this url in the request:

```
com.amazon.mobile.shopping.web://amazon.com
```

The scheme `com.amazon.mobile.shopping.web` seems to allow amazon links to be opened in their application.